# 404 Errors for files uploaded via SFTP on a Wordpress running on a Google Compute Engine Virtual Machine

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, browser, google-compute-engine, sftp

I am running a Wordpress Install (OpenLiteSpeed) in a Google Cloud Compute VM running Ubuntu

I can access the main folder of Wordpress via web browser by typing in the static IP - but I cannot access individual files and/or folders on my machine via web browser.

I would like to share files by posting links to files located in on the VM, Wordpress install folder.
How can I do that?
My permissions of the folder inside the worpress install are:

```
thisisme@wordpress-vm:~$ ls -la /var/www/html/myFolder
total 432
drwxrwxrwx 2 thisisalsome thisisalsome   4096 Mar 21 09:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 thisisalsome users     4096 Mar 21 09:59 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 thisisalsome thisisalsome 433790 Mar 21 09:02 pic.jpg
```

Comment: By saying "access via web browser" you mean SSH session in a browser?
It sounds very, very strange if you wan't to share some wordpress internal files of your running WP istance(?) vie some Web Link? - not very understandable

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No i mean - i want to upload filet via sftp and then generate a url link and use it as a "ftp server". For example i upload a file into var/www/newFolder/pic.jp and then I want to send this link to someone to download the file. I can upload the file now - but when I paste the link into the browser i get 404 wordpress page.

Comment: What is the folder from where Wordpress is served? What is the folder in which you dumped the files that you want to make available for download? What is your wordpress URL (you can leave the hostname out)?

Comment: @Octavian thanks for your answer. Wordpress is served from /var/www/html/index.php right now I have not yet hooked up my domain via DNS - I configured my VIrtual Machine to have a static IP so when I type https://xx.xx.xxx.xxx into the browser the wordpress page is served without problems. The folder I want to use as my resource folder to be accessible from outside is located in /var/www/myFolder

Comment: ``` thisisme@wordpress-vm:~$ ls -la /var/www/myFolder
total 432
drwxrwxrwx 2 thisisalsome thisisalsome   4096 Mar 21 09:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 thisisalsome users     4096 Mar 21 14:41 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 thisisalsome thisisalsome 433790 Mar 21 09:02 pic.jpg ```  these are the permissions for myFolder now - when i type https://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/myFolder/pic.jpg into the browser I get the 404 page error

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the /var/www/myFolder folder into the /var/www/html folder and access files by hostname/myFolder/myFile.zip or to configure the webserver to serve your myFolder under a different dns.

That is probably because your default webserver's configuration only serves files from the /var/www/html folder.

Comment: I just did exacly as You say. MyFolder is inside /var/www/html now - no change whatsoever. When I type https://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/myFolder/pic.jpg i still get the 404 page error

Comment: Did you use the exact same capitalization for the name of the folder and for it's name inside the URL link? eg if your file is located at /var/www/html/MyFolder/pic.jpg and you access hostname/myFolder/pic.jpg, it won't work when you have an UNIX server.

Comment: I did use the same capitalisation - but i just realised I made the mistake of using the wrong access path - i was typing https://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/html/myFolder/pic.jpg but I should have used https://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/myFolder/pic.jpg - AND NOW IT WORKS !! Thanks for pointing that out for me! I did not know UNIX servers are case sensitive!! :) Thanks For Your Help!

Answer (score 0):

@Octavian

I did use the same capitalisation - but i just realised I made the mistake of using the wrong access path - i was typing

```
xx.xx.xxx.xxx/html/myFolder/pic.jpg
```

but I should have used

```
xx.xx.xxx.xxx/myFolder/pic.jpg
```

- AND NOW IT WORKS !! Thanks for pointing that out for me! I did not know UNIX servers are case sensitive!! :) Thanks For Your Help!